# Embedding actions in production body of if-else in yacc?

Tags: yacc

I have made a yacc file trying to convert a miniC language (limited features) into a three address code. Here is the code snippet I am having a conflict in

```
/*initialization and headers*/
body: body line
|
;

line:
 branch
/* other features like declarations etc */
;

branch: if_else
;

if_else:
 IF '(' boolean ')' {// finalize evaluation of the boolean} block {//finalize block}
| IF '(' boolean ')' {// finalize evaluation of the boolean} block {//finalize block} ELSE {//initialization for else block} block {//finalize block}
;

block: '{' body '}'
;
```

Currently I am just trying to implement single `if` and single `if-else`.

This is giving me shift reduce conflict and says the actions in the second production body of the `if_else` are useless.

Why is this happening? How should I reorganize this grammar? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That shift/reduce conflict is normal in that case and is not a problem at all. Yacc (or bison) choose the shift over the reduce on a shift/reduce conflict, which is the expected behavior on a pending `else` in the C langage (as well as for all programming langages) because an `else` is always expected to be attached to the innermost if-statement. This is explained with more details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Shift_002fReduce.html).

The real problem will come from the reduce/reduce conflict introduced by the mid-rule actions in your `if_else` rule (by the couple of actions "finalize evaluation of the boolean"). When you introduce a mid-rule action yacc replace it by a generated epsilon rule (a rule with an empty production). So, you have these 2 mid-rule actions and yacc has to decide which one it should execute by reducing its associated epsilon rule. By default yacc will choose the first one. The problem is that by making that choice it definitely discards the other production (the one with the `else`). Hence the fact it tells you that that production is useless.

But the solution is simple: remove the mid-rule actions. You do not need them and should be able to manage all actions needed in the semantic actions (at the end of the productions).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by P.PICARD, the real problem is the reduce/reduce conflict coming from the duplicated mid-rule action.  You can resolve that by combining them into a single (explicit) epsilon rule.

```
if_else:
  IF '(' boolean ')' _finalize_bool block {//finalize block}
| IF '(' boolean ')' _finalize_bool block {//finalize block} ELSE {//initialization for else block} block {//finalize block}
;

_finalize_bool: {// finalize evaluation of the boolean}
```

This is complicated if the block in question needs to access the value from `boolean` -- it now needs to use $-1 instead of $2.  You may be able to clean that up by splitting off the entire condition:

```
if_else:
  IF condition block {//finalize block}
| IF condition block {//finalize block} ELSE {//initialization for else block} block {//finalize block}
;

condition: '(' boolean ')' {// finalize evaluation of the boolean}
```

You may also find it useful to move most of the `//finalize block` into the action for the `block` so you can get rid of one of the mid-action rules in the IF-ELSE case